# Open JDK 11 and javah in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, java-11

I switched my java version from java 8 to java 11 , and it seems that in java 11 javah is removed from JDK bin folder, before I was executing the javah command in my pom.xml like below

```
<execution>
      <id>javah</id>
      <goals>
         <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <configuration>
          <executable>javah</executable>
              <arguments>
                  <argument>-classpath</argument>
                  <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
                  <argument>-d</argument>
                  <argument>${build.path}/include</argument>
               </arguments>
      </configuration>
 </execution>
```

Since javah has been removed from JDK 11 how can I replace the above javah command with javac -h in my pom to work with java 11

The error I get is

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (javac -h) on project myProject: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Could you share what didn't work for you with `javac -h` and how were you configuring it?

Comment: see the above edit

Comment: The recommendation, since JDK 8, has been to use `javac -h` rather than `javah`. The `javah` tool was removed in JDK 10 via JEP 313.

Answer (score 5):

You should modify your execution as :

```
<execution>
    <id>javach</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <configuration>
        <executable>javac</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
            <argument>-h</argument>
            <argument>${build.path}/include</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

based on the the `javac --help`

> ```
>   -h <directory>
>         Specify where to place generated native header files
> ```

Comment: I get this error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (javac -h) on project myProject: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: @wearybands Can you execute using `mvn verify -X` and share the detailed command e.g. `[DEBUG] Executing command line: [javac, -classpath, .../target/classes, -h, .../include]`, next to which the exact cause would be listed for the error.

Comment: sure just give me a few minutes

Comment: [DEBUG] Executing command line: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javac.exe, -classpath, C:\sb\build\gui\myProject\bin\classes, -d, C:\sb\build/include, -h, myProject]
error: no source files
[ERROR] Command execution failed.

Comment: 1. ***no source files*** is the cause then. 2. Ensure the path `myProject` exists 3. doesn't the path `C:\sb\build/include ` look weird to you?

Comment: Can you see my edited question the modified pom.xml now

Comment: @wearybands the values to the arguments are still incorrect to what I could observe. `-h` expects the directory where you want to generate the native header files... `-d` expects the directory where to place the generated class files i.e. corresponding `.class` file for your `.java` files..

Comment: This answer is not helpful or correct. The semantics between `javah` and `javac -h` have changed drastically, with the current answer you would need to hardcode both the .java paths and the .class output paths.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to generate the sources, this time by adding on to the `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```xml
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>-h</arg>
    <!-- where to put include files (change to whatever) -->
    <arg>${project.basedir}/src/main/c++/include</arg>
    <arg>-d</arg>
    <!-- where to put the generated .class files (probably don't change this) -->
    <arg>${project.build.outputDirectory}</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```