# Is it possible to generate JNI header out of bytecodes?

Tags: java, scala, java-native-interface

With OpenJDK 11 in use, I'm writing a scala app with some APIs implemented by C, and then bind scala and C together.

However, since `javah` has been removed, I'd like to generate bytecodes from scala source file, then generate JNI header out of the bytecodes. But I know no way to achieve that.

Really appreciate if someone helps me out~ Or offer a demo of JNI using scala based on JDK11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open JDK 11 and javah in pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020303/open-jdk-11-and-javah-in-pom-xml)

Comment: I have used SWIG and it really helps: https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_overview

Comment: I think not. Because it assumes `javac` is executed against java source files, which don't exist in my scala case. @GyroGearless

Comment: SWIG is too heavy for me.@EmilianoMartinez

Comment: I implemented a sentencepiece(https://github.com/google/sentencepiece) Spark estimator using SWIG. It is a little hard at the beginning, but it works well. Take a look to this example: https://anyline.com/news/java-c-swig-type-maps

Comment: Does Scala support declaring `native` methods? If it does, I would assume the scala compiler also has a way to generate the header file from that declaration. Otherwise you might be able to have a java class with the `native` methods compiled with `javac` and `-h`, and then reference that from scala.

Comment: I found no way of generating JNI by tools like scalac. Indirection by means of java sources seems the only way for now. @JornVernee